# Is there a reference implementation for OASIS KMIP?

Tags: security, key, kmip

Is there an open source implementation or reference implementation for OASSIS KMIP specification ?

https://www.oasis-open.org/standards#kmipspecv1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reference implementation, but there are a few Open Source implementations that I am aware of:

- [KMIP4J](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kmip4j/):  Implementation of KMIP 1.0 in Java.
- [PyKMIP](https://github.com/OpenKMIP/PyKMIP):  Implementation of KMIP 1.1 in Python.